# Write XML dynamically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to know how I could dynamically write the data below in Java. I am stuck on how you write the "layout_alignParent" can set the gravity of each text view....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I know that the code below would not work. But how could I re-write it for it to work?

```
RelativeLayout m = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.tileContainerME);
EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
EditText et4 = new EditText(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);        
et1.setLayoutParams(params);
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);  
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);    
et2.setLayoutParams(params);
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);     
et3.setLayoutParams(params);
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);      
et4.setLayoutParams(params);
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

et1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
et1.setHint("Test");
et2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
et2.setHint("Test");
et3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
et3.setHint("Test");
et4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
et4.setHint("Test");

m.addView(et1);
m.addView(et2);
m.addView(et3);
m.addView(et4);
```

Comment: The "code below" is not "code", it is data.  XML data.  Once you understand this, it becomes easy as each XML element corresponds to a property of the object or it's parent which you can determine from the documentation.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html.  A simple Google search will then offer many examples of how to set these properties in code.

Comment: Now that I understand it is data, I looked through the link you gave me, it only showed me the methods that I would need, but I am asking about how I can implement them through a simple example. Could you provide me with one perhaps?

Comment: Kostya's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will help you:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Edited:

```
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks! Would gravity be written as follows?    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: How would I then remove the rule stated for the other textViews?